# SignalR Authorize is being called multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, authorize-attribute

I am trying to keep track of connected users to my hub.
The way I tried to do this was by creating a custom Authorize attribute for my hub, and checking for the user that is trying to connect. If the user is already connected then the hub does not authorize the connection

```
public class SingleHubConnectionPerUserAttribute : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private static readonly HashSet<UserKey> connections = new HashSet<UserKey>();

        public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
        {
            Type hubType = hubDescriptor.HubType;
            string userId = request.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            UserKey userKey = new UserKey(hubType, userId);

            if (connections.Contains(userKey) || !base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request))
            {
                return false;
            }

            connections.Add(userKey);
            return true;
        }
}
```

This would work fine if the method AuthorizeHubConnection was called only once per connection, but that is not what is happening.

When I load the page that tries to connect with the hub, AuthorizeHubConnection oddly runs multiple times, and the number of times it runs is not always the same, sometimes it's 5, some it's 3, I really have no clue of what could possibly be causing it.

Do you know what could cause AuthorizeHubConnection to get called more than once?

Comment: Where are you putting the attribute? If you put the attribute on the hub itself, it will get called every time a method on the hub is called. I am not 100% certain of this which is why I added it as a comment.

Comment: How many users are connecting to the hub? Do you only have 1 instance of your app running (1 browser window)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Authorization is invoked each time SignalR server receives an HTTP request before it does anything else (See: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/PersistentConnection.cs#L161). While SignalR maintains a logically persistent connection it makes multiple HTTP Requests behind the scenes. When using Websockets transport you will typically see only 3 of these when starting the connection (for the negotiate, connect and start requests) and one for each reconnect. longPolling and serverSentEvents transport create an HTTP request each time to send data (send). In addition longPolling creates a polling HTTP request to receive data (poll). Each of these requests has to be authorized so this is the reason why you see multiple calls to the AuthorizeHubConnection method.

Comment: That's right! Thank you. I put my authorization logic on the negotiation request, now it's working perfectly :)